# Why aren't object oriented database management systems more popular?

Tags: database, object-oriented-database

I mean, with EJB, LINQ2SQL, EF etc we're trying to (at least in my perspective) map the rdb in a way so we can use the entities as objects. How come there hasn't been a surge of OODBMS since they should remove many barriers we face today, or at least lessen the burden?

I'm probably overlooking something but the main reason I can see as a cause for the lack of OODBMS would be that the DBmafia clings hard to what they do best. Maybe they're even trying to halt some efforts.

Someone should be able to answer this in a way that will convince most of us.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it is because SQL and RDBMS has become de-facto standard long before OODBMS emerged. Most, if not all, of database application developers are capable of using SQL and designing relational database, while only few knows how to work with OODBMS. When something has been popular for a long time, we will need more than 'technical advantages' to fight with it.

The real reason that OODBMS is not more popular, though, is that it has not become popular yet because lacks of support from influential company e.g. Microsoft or Google. C# and Android is the example of the technology that become popular not only because its technial aspect.

Comment: Even if it's stupid, I can't stop comparing OODBMS to netbooks. They weren't pushed out by enormous marketing machines like the iPad but a lot of people saw a utilitarian product that was somehow totally missing before. My point is that this exact effect should have emerged or should emerge with OODBMS as soon as there's a system good enough to use. But yes, you've got many valid points I think.